# Paste to the last empty row

Tags: excel, vba

My code generates an "application-defined or object-defined error" trying to paste to the last available row in the column.

```
sub pastelastrow()

Dim Dec18 As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim a As Long
Dim Template As Worksheet

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set Dec18 = wb.Sheets("Dec18")
Set Template = wb.Sheets("Template")

a = Dec18.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Dec18.Range("A1:C" & a).Copy_ 
Destination:=Template.Range("B1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)

end sub
```

Comment: if Template has no data,  Range("B1").End(xlDown) is last cell,  and Offset(1, 0) is last cell's  next cell.  Sheet not recognize that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change like this.

```
Destination:=Template.Range("B" & rows.count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
```

Comment: Thank you that makes complete sense, and mine now works!